# Having issues with functions in this program

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to Python and I was having a bit of trouble with this practice exam question.

I think I have everything sorted but whenever I run the program it simply returns area and circumference as 0 so I'm not exactly sure what the issue is.

The question and my code are attached, any help would be appreciated since I have my actual exam in a month and a bit so I really need to get a handle on this issue by then lol [question image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3dR1.png)

```
# Import libraries
# -------------------------------------------------------------------

# ===> import a library that can be used to obtain a value for Pi

import math
# -------------------------------------------------------------------
# Global variables
# -------------------------------------------------------------------
PI = math.pi
# Hard coded for testing
radius = 5.7
area = 0.0
circumference = 0.0

# -------------------------------------------------------------------
# Subprograms
# -------------------------------------------------------------------

def getCircumference(radius):
    # ===> complete the calculation for circumference
    circumference = radius * 2 * PI
    # ===> return the circumference
    return circumference
# ===> create a new subprogram named getArea that takes the radius as an
# ===> input and returns the area
def getArea(radius):
    area = PI * (radius*radius)
    return area


# -------------------------------------------------------------------
# Main program
# -------------------------------------------------------------------

# ===> Call the subprograms, passing the radius and
# ===> put the returned values into the correct variables

getCircumference(radius)
getArea(radius)

# ===> Print the area and circumference to 1 decimal place using
# ===> string.format() by completing the pattern inside the {}
# ===> and adding the appropriate message as below.
# ===> output should be
# ===> "Area is <area>"
# ===> "Circumference is <circumference>"
# ===> where <area> and <circumference> are the values returned
print("Area is","{:1.1f}".format(area))
print("Circumference is","{:1.1f}".format(circumference))
```

Comment: You never assign the returns of the functions back - `area = getArea()` etc

Comment: circumference = getCircumference(radius)
area = getArea(radius)

Comment: You could also use the `global` keyword since you variables are global.

Comment: @Johnny Please don't.

Comment: @deceze I agree globals are sub-optimal. Just pointing out another option.

Comment: ty for all your responses, that worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the output of your function. I used a different variable name here to avoid the confusion you visibly had between the different scopes of your code. The `area` that you define in `area = 0.0` has nothing to do with the `area` in the getArea function.

You could further read on [variables and scopes](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html).

```
computed_circumference = getCircumference(radius)
computed_area = getArea(radius)
print("Area is","{:1.1f}".format(computed_area))
print("Circumference is","{:1.1f}".format(computed_circumference))
```